# Round the average in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these values in database:

| Sno | values | avg |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.06 | 0.06 |
| 2 | 5.0 | 5 |
| 3 | 7.0 | 7 |
| 4 | 25.0 | 25 |
| 5 | 24 | 24 |

I was able to round the values upto 2 decimals using this :

```sql
ceil((AVG( value ) )*100)/100 as avgs
```

That's correct if we more data but if we have single value for each sno then the average should also be like this :

| avg |
| --- |
| 0.06 |
| 5.0 |
| 7.0 |
| 25.0 |
| 24 |

How can we handle this?
Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statement for your sample data; **YOUR** attempt at an SQL statement (a complete statement not a single expression); an English description of the problem; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output for that sample data.

Comment: Do you mean you want at least one zero after the decimal point - which you don't have for 24 in the last row of your example? If so, that is a formatting question, not a calculation question. Or do you want to keep exactly what you've shown in `values` - implying that is a string, not a number, and your calculation is relying on implicit conversion?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to solve as the expected output looks to be exactly the same as the values you have in the database with the exception of `.0` appended to some values (but not all of them).

Comment: If you are taking averages, then the inputs must be numbers, not strings. If they are numbers, how are you able to display, in the same columns, both 25.0 and 24? Don't even think about any of your calculations - just look at your input column, called `values`. Of course, as a number, 25.0 is the same as 25, and a number column can only be displayed in one format. The whole thing doesn't make sense before you even ask a question about "average" and "rounding".

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that those values are strings.

If there's only one then show the MAX instead of the AVG.

> ```
> create table test (
>  sno number, 
>  value varchar2(12)
> );
> insert into test (sno, value)
> select 1 sno, '0.06' value from dual union all
> select 2, '5.0' from dual union all
> select 3, '7.0' from dual union all
> select 4, '25.02' from dual union all
> select 9, '4321.12' from dual union all
> select 9, '1234.21' from dual union all
> select 5, '24' from dual;
> ```

> ```
> select sno
> , case
>   when count(value) = 1 then max(value)
>   else to_char(round(avg(value), 2)) 
>   end as "avg" 
> from test t
> group by sno
> ```

| SNO | avg |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 2777.67 |
| 2 | 5.0 |
| 4 | 25.02 |
| 3 | 7.0 |
| 5 | 24 |
| 1 | 0.06 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=efddbe35f88b316c8da9685451291909)*